# Mapping data that contains dots in React

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, mapping

I am trying to `map` the data in `React` that is coming from the `API` but I am having problems mapping the object that contains `dots` for example this: `name.en_US`. 
What is the proper way to map this object and keeping the data structure that I have?

I am getting the date in this format from the API:

```
{
    "user": "User",
    "employeeId": "0000",
    "businessCustomer": "customer",
    "endCustomer": {
        "name": "",
        "address": "",
        "place": ""
    },
    "device": {
        "shipmentIds": "23",
        "name.en_US": "wasi",
        "name.fi_FI": " masi"
    },
    "task": {
        "time": "2019-02-10T16:55:46.188Z",
        "duration": "00:00:24",
        "sum": "75€"
    }
},
```

And then I am trying to map it using the following code.

```
  const {
    user,
    employeeId,
    businessCustomer,
    endCustomer,
    device,
    task
  } = task;

  const{
    endCustomerName,
    address,
    place
  } = endCustomer;

  const {
    shipmentIds,
    names
  } = device;

  const{
    en_US,
    fi_FI
  } = names;

  const {
    time,
    duration,
    summa
  } = task;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const data = {
    "user": "User",
    "employeeId": "0000",
    "businessCustomer": "customer",
    "endCustomer": {
        "name": "",
        "address": "",
        "place": ""
    },
    "device": {
        "shipmentIds": "23",
        "name.en_US": "wasi",
        "name.fi_FI": " masi"
    },
    "task": {
        "time": "2019-02-10T16:55:46.188Z",
        "duration": "00:00:24",
        "sum": "75€"
    }
};

const { device } = data;

const {
    shipmentIds,
    'name.en_US': name_en_US,
    'name.fi_FI': name_fi_FI
} = device;

const nameUS = device['name.en_US'];

console.log(name_en_US, nameUS);
```

Use `[ ]` notation like, `device['name.en_US']` .

Comment: And where would I add this? Inside the device const or as a separate const?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't destructure the object with these. So you can use a new constant or use  it directly wherever needed, like: `const usName = device['name.en_US'];`

Comment: That's odd. I could make it work with both answers. Adding a snippet with the data.

Comment: I removed the comment, but the issue was that it was `names.` not `name`. I had copied the older data, which was completely my fault.

Answer (score 2):

You can destructure your propery as @Vishnu mentioned, or you could also destructure it by providing a valid key name

```
const {
    shipmentIds,
    'name.en_US': name_en_US,
    'name.fi_FI': name_fi_FI
} = device;
```

And then you could access your variable with `name_en_US`.